# Mysql - Select must contain all

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem.

100 buckets.  7 TYPES of balls, and allowed to have up to and including 7 balls in each bucket (only one of each type max in each bucket).

I want to extract all bucketid's that have AT LEAST the ball types from a given array (for example: 1,3,6) .

```
MYSQL: bucketid, ballid - with (bucketid,ballid) as unique.

SELECT bucketid FROM table WHERE ballid IN (1,3,6)
```

But this returns incorrect results...

How do I do this?

If it's not possible, is there a better table structure I should be using?

Comment: A combination of [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) should do the trick.

Comment: Your query should give you the results you need. If it doesn't, could you provide us with the table structures and some data?

Comment: The query returns bucketid's including those which have just one of the ballid's or a subset of the ballid's.  I want it to be an absolute condition, like the bucketid must have ALL the ballid's listed in it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT bucketid FROM bucket
GROUP BY bucketid
HAVING 
  COUNT(IF(ballid = 1, 1, NULL)) AND
  COUNT(IF(ballid = 3, 1, NULL)) AND
  COUNT(IF(ballid = 6, 1, NULL));
```

Comment: Is this an intensive query?  Is there a better table structure I should use for this instead?

Comment: If this table represents many-to-many relations (when one bucketid may have many ballids and one ballid may have many bucketid), then the structure is correct. Otherwise, find more information in the internet about the database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Having a go at it with this set up (or assumption):

I created a `balls` table under the assumption that for you to know what ball id values you need to filter for, they must come from somewhere.. And my addition of the column `maybeballname` was merely to give it (having a `balls` table) a slightly bit more of meaning like what would a ball id mean? So I gave it a name as an example. Just as an example.

```
-- balls should have its own table
CREATE TABLE balls (
    ballid INT
    , maybeballname VARCHAR(10)
);
-- sample buckets
CREATE TABLE buckets (
    bucketid INT
    , ballid INT
);

--populate with data
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(1,'BALL#1');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(2,'BALL#2');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(3,'BALL#3');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(4,'BALL#4');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(5,'BALL#5');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(6,'BALL#6');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(7,'BALL#7');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(8,'BALL#8');
INSERT INTO balls VALUES(9,'BALL#9');
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(1,1);--complete (1,3,6)
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(1,3);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(1,6);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(1,4);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(2,5);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(3,1);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(4,1);--complete (1,3,6)
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(4,3);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(4,6);
INSERT INTO buckets VALUES(5,3);

-- this should return bucket id values 1 and 4, right?
SELECT bk.bucketid
FROM buckets AS bk
INNER JOIN balls AS b ON bk.ballid = b.ballid
WHERE b.ballid
IN ( 1, 3, 6 ) 
GROUP BY bk.bucketid
HAVING COUNT( bk.bucketid ) >= 3 -- at least the number of ball ids provided
-- and bucket id 1 has ballid values 1-6
```

Comment: Buckets can contain up to 7 balls, so you could have one with 1,3,6,2,7 for example...I'm thinking of using primes and storing the mulitple...

Comment: Hold on.. so what, exactly, is your rule for picking the ballid values to be returned?

Comment: The core condition is: The bucketid's returned must contain AT LEAST all the ballid's given...

Comment: @David19801 I modified the query, changing the `HAVING` statement to return those with at least the 3 you provided. This way, you just have to make sure that the number of ids you want to check will reflect in the `HAVING` clause...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little round-about because MySQL only supports [`ALL` on sub-queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html), but you should be able to get what you want with a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE bucketid = ALL (
    SELECT bucketid
    FROM table
    WHERE ballid IN (... your list of ballid's ...)
)
```